# Visual studio inline assembly direct jump

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, inline-assembly

I want to use inline assembly in visual studio to jump to a specific address. I tried this:

```
_asm {
    jmp 0x12345678
}
```

But the compiler says: "The opcode does not use operands of this type."

How can I do a direct jump?

Comment: Will the memory location always be in exactly the same place?? Surely the location will be computed when the routine runs and uses whatever memory is available on the machine. A relative jmp uses the code E9. In x86 32 bit mode a one hop short jump forward (expressed as a long jump) is E9 01 00 00 00 machine code. A dd 01E9 and a db 0 can replicate(dw 0 my be needed). Relative short jumps don't always work. Get it right or windows goes boom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand it, MASM does not support this type of jump.  You have a few options :

```
mov eax, 12345678h
jmp eax
```

or

```
push 12345678h 
ret
```

The first uses a register, the second incurs a performance hit because it rattles the CALL/RET pairing optimizations in the CPU.  You could also use a typed constant or local variable, I think - this also consumes a few extra bytes.  I don't think there's any other way, nor any direct, one-line means of performing a direct jump like this in MASM.

**caveat** : this assumes you are working in x86 code.  Your OP suggests as much from the size of the jmp argument but if this is x64 then the answer will obviously be different.

Comment: Nice. mov eax,12345678--push eax--ret works for my inline x86 asm.

Comment: @ady Curious why you would combine these and use a register - why not just bypass eax and do a direct push/ret (like the second example)?

Comment: My original prog was mov eax,location to see what went into eax. Mov eax,location jmp [eax] didn't work for me. (jmp eax did)

Comment: @ady curious...  push location -- ret, should work directly, in any case.  If you did `[eax]` and not `eax`, however, note that you're dereferencing eax rather than using it directly (because it is a register).  MASM tolerates some sloppiness with square brackets that can lead to surprises...

Comment: it seems like you are right and MASM does not have anything like a direct jump. But the x86 CPU should know some jump like this? Maybe I can encode the jump as OP code instead an mnemonic somehow? Or am I completely wrong? :D

Comment: @user2252343 - yes, other assemblers will let you do this (FASM,  for example).  It is a limitation of the microsoft inline assembler.

Answer (score 0):

Try set a var to the address:

```
unsigned int var = 0x12345678;
_asm {
    jmp [var]
}
```

Comment: ok this is a memory indirect jump. But it seems this is the closest I can get with MASM :(

Comment: I'm not an expert but perhaps MASM( (Microsoft Assembler) doesn't support absolute jumps. Try [FASM](http://flatassembler.net/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using linker options /DYNAMICBASE:NO /FIXED /BASE:0x[your base address] for your module, you can use:

```
_asm
{
    jmp label1 + 0xFFFFFF
label1:
}
```

Which in disassembly compiles to:

```
    _asm
    {
        jmp label1 + 0xFFFFFF
040117DC E9 FF FF FF 00       jmp         050117E0  
    label1:
    }
```

You can then play around to get an E9 jump to your destination address.